# Calculate function with integers as input and plotting

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I'd like to plot the function 1/2*x(x+1) in for integer values ranging from 3 to 20 and in particular I'd like the function to be plotted in those points. I have managed to create the following graph so far which obviously is not what I want

[image: Plotting 1/2*x(x+1)]

this is the code I have written:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
    xlabel={Numero di elementi},
    ylabel={Numero di coppie},
    xmin=3, xmax=20,
    ymin=0, ymax=55,
    xtick={1,...,20}
  ] 
    \addplot {0.5*x*(x-1)}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

So what is that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can adjust the calculation/plotting range with the `domain` keyword. If you want the evaluated points only for integer values of x use the `samples` keyword to select the appropriate number of `samples` within the `domain` range:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
    xlabel={Numero di elementi},
    ylabel={Numero di coppie},
    xmin=3, xmax=20,
    ymin=0, %ymax=55,
    xtick={1,...,20},
    domain={3:20},
    samples=18
  ] 
    \addplot {0.5*x*(x-1)}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Plot example]

Answer (score 8):

The other solutions here try to coerce `pgfplots` into choosing the samples at the desired locations. There is already a very explicit way to specify where you want the samples taken at and that is to use

```
samples at={<list>}
```

[image]

### Notes:

- The `samples at=` has a higher precedence than `samples` and `domain`. Hence, `samples` and `domain` are ignored when the `samples at=` is specified.
- If you need to clear a previously set `samples at=` list, you can do so via `samples at={}`.  This will re-activate the `domain` key (and also the `samples` key, but the documentation does not explicitly point this out).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
    xlabel={Numero di elementi},
    ylabel={Numero di coppie},
    xmin=3, xmax=20,
    ymin=0, ymax=55,
    xtick={1,...,20},
    samples at={3,...,20}
  ] 
    \addplot {0.5*x*(x-1)}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do I keep forgetting this? :)

Comment: @percusse: :-) Actually, I don't even know why I keep remembering this. I am pretty sure I have _never_ used it until now, but for reason it is stuck in my head.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\foreach` command.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
    xlabel={Numero di elementi},
    ylabel={Numero di coppie},
    xmin=3, xmax=20,
    ymin=0, ymax=55,
    xtick={1,...,20}
  ] 
  \foreach \n in {3,4,...,20}{
    \addplot [mark=*] coordinates {(\n,{\n*(\n-1)/2})}; 
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

But I don't get why you say `ymax=55` because then you only need to plot from 3 to 11 (the rest of points don't appear). If you want all the points to appear you should comment it.

[image: Plot]